# how to combine the common key and join the values in the dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have one list which contain a few dictionaries.

```
   [{u'TEXT242.txt': u'work'},{u'TEXT242.txt': u'go to work'},{u'TEXT1007.txt': u'report'},{u'TEXT797.txt': u'study'}]
```

how to combine the dictionary when it has the same key. for example:
u'work', u'go to work'are under one key:'TEXT242.txt', so that i can remove the duplicated key.

```
 [{u'TEXT242.txt': [u'work', u'go to work']},{u'TEXT1007.txt': u'report'},{u'TEXT797.txt': u'study'}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setdefault` method of dictionaries is handy here... it can create an empty list when a dictionary key doesn't exist, so that you can always append the value.

```
dictlist = [{u'TEXT242.txt': u'work'},{u'TEXT242.txt': u'go to work'},{u'TEXT1007.txt': u'report'},{u'TEXT797.txt': u'study'}]
newdict = {}

for d in dictlist:
    for k in d:
        newdict.setdefault(k, []).append(d[k])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import defaultdict
before = [{u'TEXT242.txt': u'work'},{u'TEXT242.txt': u'go to work'},{u'TEXT1007.txt': u'report'},{u'TEXT797.txt': u'study'}]
after = defaultdict(list)
for i in before:
    for k, v in i.items():
        after[k].append(v)
```

out:

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'TEXT1007.txt': ['report'],
             'TEXT242.txt': ['work', 'go to work'],
             'TEXT797.txt': ['study']})
```

> This technique is simpler and faster
>   than an equivalent technique using dict.setdefault()